# Storing text in an Input text box with Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to store a text value in an input element. The element is accessed by a jquery selector, where the variable selectedindex contains an integer from a dropdown list (it will contain either 0,1,2). Here is the code including the html and javascript

```
<li id="ID1">
      <p><label>Parts:</label>
           <input type="text" name="0" class="lab" />
           <input type="text" name="1"  class="lab" />
           <input type="text" name="2"  class="lab" />
      </p>
</li>


  var index = b.selectedIndex;
  var usr_input = $("#spinner").spinner("value");
  $("#ID1 > p > input[name$=index]").text(usr_input);
```

The problem is the selector doesn't find the specific input element using the variable 'index'. I hardcoded 0 into the selector for testing purposes `$("#ID1 > p > input[name$=0]").text(usr_input);` and that worked as it selected the input with name 0. How can I implement this using a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#ID1 > p > input[name$="+index+"]").val(usr_input);
```

What you need is to concatenate that variable into your selector and you can do that by ending/starting the string with `"` and using `+` which concatenates it with the variable.

If you are targeting a input you should use [**.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: Thanks! If I may ask why do you need to concatenate the variable into the selector?

Comment: @lboyel, if you don't concatenate jQuery will think its a string and look for something with name ending with "index", the word index instead of it's stored value.

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation, also use `.val()` for text inputs:

```
("#ID1 > p > input[name$=" +index + "]").val(usr_input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#ID1 > p > input[name$="+index+"]").text(usr_input);
```